# I need to design table with header text and arrow

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I need to create a table with header text and arrows. table data is dynamic from server.

My code:

```
<TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tlCurrentStatusa"
            style="@style/LayoutMatchWrap"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvUserNameLabel2">

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvUserNameLabel11"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/btn_arrow_white_down"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_tabheader"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/table_Assignment"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_bigger_size_20" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvUserNameLabel12"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_tabheader"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/table_AssignDate"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_bigger_size_20" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvUserNameLabel13"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#000"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/table_DueDate"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_bigger_size_20" />


            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tlCurrentStatus"
            style="@style/LayoutMatchWrap"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tlCurrentStatusa" />
```

Above code 2 table layouts one is for header and other one for data.

my questions:

1. Table data rows are strected depending on size of data? i need to fix same width for all like header..

Comment: Use linear layout with weight sum 3. and in that linear use relative layout with weight 1. And in relative you can set two textviews. Its for header

Comment: if we use weight sum also it will stretch depends on data size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this with creating custom row in layout and using it for header and data of table.